# Where desktop icon positions are saved in MATE?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, mate, ubuntu-mate, caja

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS. There are a lot carefully aligned icons on my desktop. Something like shown below:

[image: icons]

I can't find icon positions attributes in `dconf` / `gsettings`.

How can I backup their current positions to restore them later? Where such a file is located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick `grep`ing in home folder gives the following file name with needed information:

```
~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

It is special file to be operated by `gio info` or `gio set`.

---

Every icon has its own metadata attribute. So one can:

- read it by

  ```
  gio info -a "metadata::caja-icon-position" ~/Desktop/file1.txt
  ```

  to get something like

  > ```
  > attributes:
  >   metadata::caja-icon-position: 922,382
  > ```

  where 922 and 382 are horizontal and vertical pixel positions for `file1.txt` icon.
- write it by

  ```
  gio set -t string ~/Desktop/file1.txt metadata::caja-icon-position 300,400
  ```

  to move *file1.txt* icon to the location specified by 300 and 400 coordinates in pixels.

  Then one needs to ask Caja to refresh the desktop by calling `caja -q`.

Comment: There are also some folder icons not included in ~/Desktop/ that the system generates.  There is a text file at ~/.config/caja/desktop-metadata that stores the position information.  You can edit any of the icon locations in the text file and run caja -q and these icons will move to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bash script that will save and load icon positions.  Usage is

```
./icons.sh save [name]
./icons.sh load [name]
```

The name argument is optional, in case you want to save different configurations.  You may have to adjust the lines under #config info to accommodate your OS.

```
#!/bin/bash

#config info
desktop=~/Desktop/*
metastr="metadata::caja-icon-position"
metafile=~/.config/caja/desktop-metadata
saveicon=~/.icon.txt
savemeta=~/.iconmeta.txt
file_manager=caja

saveinfo(){
cat /dev/null > "$saveicon"
for f in $desktop;do
p=$(gio info -a "$metastr" "$f"|grep "$metastr"|awk '{print $2}')
echo "$f;$p">>"$saveicon"
done
#save metafile
cp "$metafile" "$savemeta"
zenity --notification --window-icon="/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/categories/applications-other.png" --text "Icon Positions Saved"
}

loadinfo(){
str=$(cat "$saveicon")
if [ -z "$str" ];then
echo "$saveicon not found"
exit
fi

for fl in $str;do
f=$(echo "$fl"|cut -d';' -f1)
p=$(echo "$fl"|cut -d';' -f2)
gio set -t string "$f" "$metastr" "$p"
done
#load metafile
cp "$savemeta" "$metafile"
#restart file manager
pkill "$file_manager"
}

if [ -z "$1" ];then
echo "Saves or loads icon positions"
echo " Usage:"
echo "$0 save [name]"
echo "$0 load [name]"
exit
fi

if [ -n "$2" ];then
  saveicon="$2"
  savemeta="$2_meta"
fi

if [ "$1" = "save" ];then
saveinfo
fi

if [ "$1" = "load" ];then
loadinfo
fi
```