# Ubuntu 20.04 : How to set a custom icon via command line / gio set metadata::custom-icon not writable

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to assign custom icons via the bash shell using "gio set" in the following manner:
"gio set -t string $FOLDERPATH metadata::custom-icon file://$FILEPATH"
where $FOLDERPATH is the folder, and $FILEPATH is the image to be assigned, and receive the following error:
gio: Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon not supported

"gio info --query-writable $FOLDERPATH" does not show metadata::custom-icon as writable, but it appears that this used to be possible using "gio set" or "gvfs-set-attribute". **Is there any method to set a custom icon via command line or has this been fully deprecated?**

EDIT: Here's an example of the command I am trying without variables:
"gio set -t string /home/dud/test metadata::custom-icon file:///home/dud/test/test.jpg". Has anyone tested this or set custom icons via command line in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Chem the man page. It may be that the option -t must come after specifiying LOCATION, ATTRIBUTE and VALUE. Anyway, you could simply remove `-t string` in this case because it is the default

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, but that's not pertinent. Omitting or changing the placement of '-t string' makes no difference. As I stated, it seems it used to be possible to set custom icons, but 'gio' and 'gvfs-set-attribute' no longer seem to have that functionality. Do you have any info on helping to set custom icons?

Comment: Check possible syntax at https://askubuntu.com/a/1320321/66509 .

Comment: Syntax looks good, but obviously we do not know about the variables. They are not quoted, so there could be an issue.

Comment: Edited question with specific variables. Here's hoping someone actually addresses the question.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem, maybe you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874201/gio-command-wont-display-metadatacustom-icon-attribute/76742254#76742254

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already fix the problem but for the people of the future:

Are you writing correctly the command? It is very tricky to make it works, I had a lot of problems because the path of picture has a space and because of the slashes '/'.

The command should be like this example: `gio set $HOME/Documents/C metadata::custom-icon file://$HOME/Pictures/App_Logos/C.png`

DO NOT USE SPACES! Using `\`  don't works,

I have created a bash script to change icons in bulk, [check it here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2288902)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem too,
Maybe it was coursed by a wrong version of gio, you can try this here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874201/gio-command-wont-display-metadatacustom-icon-attribute/76742254#76742254